# Selector not working for button inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, selector, imagebutton

I want my imagebutton to show a different image when the button is touched (pressed down). For this I usually use a selector, but this time it only loads the "btnnormal" image but not the "btnselected" image when the button is pressed down. The button is in a fragment and I think this causes this problem somehow. This code normally works perfectly fine with a normal activity.

This is my xml file in res/drawable/buttonone.xml with the selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btnselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btnselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btnselected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btnnormal" />
</selector>
```

This is my layout file in res/layout/fragment_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonone" /> //here is the reference to the selector 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my java file in java/StartFragment.java :

```
public class StartFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fraglayoutv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null);

    btnOne = (ImageButton) fraglayoutv.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //here is what happens when the button is clicked
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the "btnselected" image doesn't show up when the button is pressed down?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: does nobody have a clue ?

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you got any solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to set in ImageButton

```
android:clickable="true"
```